# vba code for filter on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Filter()
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
For k = 1 To j
With Worksheets(k)
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="tatamotors"
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="29-oct-15"
End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Above code found on web search and done small modification as per my need. It is working fine. Need some help from experts. I keep changing different name in autofilter field 1, i.e. instead of tatamotors sometimes wants to filter out ACC, sometimes RELIANCE etc. Could experts help me here, that instead of making changes inside code, show inputbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fabrizio, I made some changes as per my need and now working fine.The revised code as follows.

```
Sub Filter_Click()
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
Dim key1 As String
key1 = InputBox("Type Script Name", "Title")
For k = 1 To j
With Worksheets(k)
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=key1
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="29-oct-15"
End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

yes an idea will be to use on eimput box to define the filter key:

```
Sub Filter_Click()
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
j = Worksheets.Count
Dim key1 As String
Dim key2 As String
key1 = InputBox("Type your key search", "Title")
key2 = InputBox("Type your key search", "Title")
For k = 1 To j
With Worksheets(k)
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=ky1
.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=ky2
End With
Next k
End Sub
```

one other can be to use a form with one selectbox to choose the available criteria, because otherwise you can type one value missing in your data range